# Multiple PHP Functions in one file

Tags: php, isset

So i am trying to have a single PHP file to perform 2-3 different functions.

Basically when the page loads(test.php) it will load generic html elements on the page. It would load a jquery tab ui as well as a combo box that is populated from a sql database.

Both of the above html elements i have working fine, no problems there but The generation of the jquery ui tabs and the sql/combo box generation are in separate PHP files. I want to combine both of those steps into one single file.

On initial page load it loads the two elements from steps above but then i need to get the page to post to itself(test.php) if the combo box has an onChange event or onClick event. I have been reading about using isset() or empty() but i am not exactly sure how to go about this in a correct way.

Any suggestions or examples of this in action? Im pretty sure this has been asked many times but i am not finding a solution thus far.

dropdown.php

```
<?php
//Create the DB populated dropdown list

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "_user", "_pass");


$tables = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM _dropdown");
mysql_select_db("items", $con);

echo '<select id="Type" onChange="dropChange();">';
echo '<option value="" style="display:none;"></option>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($tables)) {
    foreach($row as $value){
        $i = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $value ORDER BY name ASC", $con);
        echo '<optgroup label="'.ucfirst($value).'"></optgroup>';
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($i)){
            echo '<option id="'.$value.'" value="'.$row2[0].'">'.$row2[0].'</option>';
        }
    }   
}
echo '</select>';

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

tabs.php

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "_user", "_pass");
mysql_select_db("_database", $con) or die (mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM _table") or die (mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
mysql_close($con);


echo '
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
                    ui.panel.html(
                        "Couldn\'t load this tab. We\'ll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn\'t be a demo." );
                });
            }
        });
    </script>

    <ul>
        <li id="S1"><a href="#S1">S1</a></li>
        <li id="S2"><a href="#S2" style="color:red; text-decoration:line-through">S 2</a></li>
        <li id="S3"><a href="#S3" style="color:red; text-decoration:line-through">S 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>
    <div id="s1">

    </div>
    <div id="s2">

    </div>
    <div id="s3">

    </div>  
    ';

?>
```

So i am trying to have "test.php" combine these two scripts into one page(test.php) and perform both functions. Instead of having ***onChange="dropChange();"*** in the dropdown.php page wouldnt it be something like:

```
onChange='<? php $_POST["PHP_SELF"] ?>'
```

Comment: show some code to explain this. I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Agree with @MarcB, but as a shot in the dark... If a checkbox isn't set it's not in the POST request. So either empty() or !isset() will test for the non existence. Also use include()/require() to pull in other files. Let me see your code and I'll be able to tighten up my suggestions.

Comment: Use mysqli_ instead of mysql_. See red info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jquery, you can add an event monitor at the top of the page to make the page think the form has been submitted as if a submit button was clicked -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id_of_your_drop_down").onChange(function(event){
       event.preventDefault(); //prevents the usual redraw behavior
       $("#id_of_your_submit_button").click() //triggers form submission for that submit
       }
    });
});
```

You could just put $("#id_of_your_submit_button").click() in place of dropChange(); but the above method is better practice.

Comment: As this was untested, you may need to remove the preventDefault line to allow the field to re-populate with the user selection before the submission event occurs.

Comment: So am i still calling one of the functions on the test.php page with the jquery click() event?

Comment: You would essentially be calling whatever the page action is. the click() action acts as a user clicking, and since it's a submit button, click() submits the form to it's action, which is your php page.